# In Ruby on Rails, a method defined in view cannot override a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a debug method that can print out some debug info, and this debug method is defined in `application_helper.rb`  To disable this method, so that no debug info is printed for this file, I added

```
def debugp; return nil; end
```

in the view file that uses the original `debugp`... but it seems that this new definition cannot override the original definition of `debugp` (because debug info is still printed out).  Is there a way to override it?  There are other methods to disable the printing, but I'd like to find out the part about override a method in the application helper.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the method in the view file, however you can override it in the corresponding helper - if you used the Rails generator to generate your controller, then it would have generated a helper too, for example, a "people" controller would have these files:

- app/controllers/people_controller.rb
- app/views/people/*.html.erb
- app/helpers/people_helper.rb

So to override a helper method from the application helper, put your helper method definition not in the view, but in the helper:

```
module PeopleHelper
  def debugp; return nil; end
end
```

Hope that helps,